# Pre declared dictionary size limit?

Tags: python, dictionary, size, limit, predefined-variables

I have a big dictionary i constantly reference in my code so i have it initialized at the top:

```
import ...

myDictionary = {'a':'avalue','b':'bvalue',...}

code ...
```

But when i try to get values, some of the keys are not found.  It appears as though Python is chopping my dictionary due to a size limit.  I tried searching google but couldn't find anything on this.

I ended up dumping the key:value mappings into a separate file and wrote a function that would build the dictionary by reading in the file.

It would be nice to know why this is happening... even better to find a cleaner way to still have my dictionary.

EDIT: Dictionary has over 1,700 keys

Comment: how many keys does the dict have?

Comment: I'd store that dictionary in a file.  It's no problem for a dictionary, but kind of excessive for a line of code.

Comment: 1700 is nothing.  You have mis-loaded the dictionary.  Your bug is in your loading, not in the dictionary itself.  Post the smallest piece of loading code that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Looks good here (python 2.6.6):
> d = {}

> for i in xrange(1700):

>     d[unicode(i)] = i

> len(d)

> 1700

Comment: `dict( (x,x) for x in range(10000) )`  A 10,000 element dictionary.  Works great.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you might want to look for is that the keys in your dictionary are not duplicates. For example, in the following code:

```
>>> d = {'1': 'hello', '2': 'world', '1': 'new'}
>>> d
{'1': 'new', '2': 'world'}
>>>
```

because I used the key `'1'` twice, only the last one appeared and thus I was left with a dictionary of size 2 rather than 3.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have a dictionary size limit. I've had dictionaries with well over 1 million keys. Could you post more of the code?

Comment: i wrote a simple test script where i pre-declared a big dictionary and just printed out the length: len(myDictionary) and it the reported size was not even close to what it was supposed to be.  It seems that pre-declared dictionary have different max lengths (memory limits) than dictionaries built one key at a time...
I have asked my friends to try and they see the same weird result... not gonan post a 1,700 key dictionary, its easy to make:

Comment: myDictionary = {
'0':'0',
'1':'1',
'2':'2',
...

Try just 300

Comment: @makoto: What version of Python are you using? I just created a source file with a 1000000 element dict literal, and the length was correctly reported.

Comment: @makato: Can you post full code on gist.github.com or something that exhibits this behavior?  Also mention your platform and version of python. Thanks!